# Передача текста при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Есть div и несколько кнопок, при клике на кнопку необходимо заменить текст в div. Изменять атрибуты - не проблема, но как изменять текст?

Comment: юзайте innerHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML = 'Ваш текст';
```

Comment: @andreyqin Большое спасибо:)

Comment: @andreyqin, не лучше ли использовать textContent?

Comment: @dzhioev, textContent нужно в связке с innerText юзать